# how do i install a particular ros version

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install 1.11.16 ros indigo 1.11.16 and not the latest indigo release how do I do that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238520/how-do-i-install-a-particular-ros-version/) by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you mean "with `apt-get`", then you can't. The ROS repositories aren't set up that way, and only contain the latest version of the packages. Afaik, that is more a `reprepro` limitation than anything the OSRF has configured.

From source it can be done, but you'd have to know the exact versions of all the packages involved. Possible, but it'd be quite some effort.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-19**:
For future readers: perhaps [rosinstall_generator_time_machine](https://github.com/rosin-project/rosinstall_generator_time_machine) can do this.